# AdMob for Windows Phone 8 FailedToReceiveAd NetworkError

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob

I need to add AdMob banner to my app. But I catch FailedToReceiveAd event with NetworkError message on emulator and on device. Example from official site behave the same way. WebBrowser and other network tasks work with network good.

Plese help, because i can't find any solutions of this proplem.

Comment: check with permissions to your app it requires some permissions

Comment: @SmartDeveloper which permissions?

Comment: check my below answer @creepycrawl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the mandatory and optional capabilities for your app. You can modify your app's capabilities by opening WMAppManifest.XML and selecting the Capabilities tab.
Also check adRequest.ForceTesting = true; it must be false

[image]